# Is there any way to enforce the type of an uninstantiated class?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in typescript to enforce the type of an uninstantiated class?

Below I want to enforce that only classes that extend `Repository` can be passed to the `addRepository` method but I do not want to instantiate the class when being passed in (its constructor should be only be called by the service container).

Is there any way to do this?

```
import { Repository } from '../repositories/repository';

class Factory {

  addRepository(repositoryClass: Repository) /* <- seriously what can go here? */ { }
}

class UserRepository extends Repository {

}

let factory = new Factory();

factory.addRepository(UserRepository); // throws error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator:

```
class Factory {
  addRepository(repositoryClass: typeof Repository) { }
}
```

Comment: You're a saint!